# Autofac create 2 instances of service

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, autofac

Autofac resolves as 2 separate instances when I expect one instance per API request.

I see one instance from controller till a command handler and another instance in one of my domain event handlers, the domain handler references the dispatcher object through property injection.

The problem here is I am not seeing the same object instance of **UserContext** where I inject and modify through and Web API controller in my Domain event handler which invokes through `DomainEvent.dispatcher.Raise();`.

I follow the same instruction as per Autofac doc. Could anybody shed some light on what I am missing here?

```
//Auotfac registration  
public class AutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
         builder
            .RegisterType<DomainEventDispatcher>()
            .As<IDomainEventDispatcher>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

         builder
            .RegisterType<DomainEvent>()
            .As<IDomainEvent>).PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope().AutoActivate();

         builder
            .RegisterType<UserContext>()
            .As<IApplicationContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}

//My DomainEvent class
//--------------------------
internal class DomainEvent:IDomainEvent
{
    public static IDomainEventDispatcher dispatcher { get;  set; }
}
```

Comment: where do you resolve the `IDomainEventDispatcher`  instance ? can you show more code so we can help ?

Comment: it through property injection and I am autoactivating it. Since this is a static object I can use this from my class like below 

    
`builder.RegisterType<DomainEvent>().As<IDomainEvent> 
       ().PropertiesAutowired().InstancePerLifetimeScope().AutoActivate();`

`await DomainEvent.dispatcher?.Raise<Ttype>(@event);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be hard to figure out because you didn't provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That example and all code related to your question should be in the question - if there are questions asked through comments... update your question with the answers.

That said, I can see a pitfall that is probably what you're falling into.

First, I see this:

```cs
builder
  .RegisterType<DomainEventDispatcher>()
  .As<IDomainEventDispatcher>()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

In ASP.NET / ASP.NET Core this will generally equate to "one instance per request," which appears to be the direction you want to go. However, it implies that *it's only resolved from request lifetime scopes*.

**The root container is a lifetime scope, too.** That's where singletons get resolved. It's also where singleton *dependencies* get resolved. [There's a looooot of documentation on lifetime scopes.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html)

This is important, because I see two other things that raise some concern.

First...

```cs
internal class DomainEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    public static IDomainEventDispatcher dispatcher { get;  set; }
}
```

The `static` there is *really concerning* because you have the dispatcher registered as instance per lifetime scope... but `static` here is going to be a threading problem. I assume (though can't verify, again, because of the lack of MCVE) you're doing something such that when a request comes in you're setting this static variable. This probably works great in development when there's only one request coming in at a time. This is going to be really bad news when you have two requests and one instance of the dispatcher stomps over the other instance.

**Don't mix static and per-request.** Static things are singletons. Always.

Second...

```cs
builder
  .RegisterType<DomainEvent>()
  .As<IDomainEvent>()
  .PropertiesAutowired()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
  .AutoActivate();
```

You have what looks to be something that should be created per-request but you also have `AutoActivate()`. That's going to resolve one of these *from the root container* at container build time. I'm not sure what's going on there, maybe a shared data connection is getting started up or something, but that means you're getting a `DomainEvent` resolved from the container at container build time and that instance *will be cached until the container is disposed* because you specified instance per lifetime scope... and, again, the container is a scope. If you were to ask for a second one of these at the root level (like for the dependency on a singleton) you'd get this root one, not the per-request one.

I assume *later* you're also getting `DomainEvent` objects resolved somewhere. Those are likely coming from the request scope if they're in controllers or something.

Thus, you have a mixed up set of requirements for scopes and activation.

- Static reference to `IDomainEventDispatcher` that will be a singleton for the whole app... but per lifetime scope registration for `IDomainEventDispatcher`.
- Auto-activate for `IDomainEvent` which will happen at the root container... but a desire to have it be per-request due to the per lifetime scope registration.

There's apparently a `UserContext` in play here, too, but there's nothing in the code that explains how it's consumed or what it's doing, so that part of the question can't be addressed.

**I would recommend:**

- Switch the `static` reference to the dispatcher to be an instance property. If you want to make the dispatcher a singleton, register it as `SingleInstance` with Autofac.
- Avoid property injection if you can. If the `DomainEvent` requires a dispatcher, put it in the constructor. That will ensure you always get one. Property injection won't fail if it can't inject a property.
- Don't use `AutoActivate` on the per-request items. If you have a shared data connection or something that needs to be fired up at container build time, separate that logic out to some sort of data provider that can be registered as a singleton. This will also avoid the root-level resolution of things that should be per-request.